# Connect app in Azure VM to SQL Server in shared environment

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Server in Azure's shared environment. I connect to it from a Web App also in shared.

I now created a VM with Windows Server 2019 to host my same Web App. My db connection fails, how do I connect the VM based Web App to the SQL Server in the shared environment?

My Web App publishes and runs from the VM like it should until it needs data.

I also installed Azure Data Studio on the VM Server and I can't get it to connect either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When I changed my publish profile in VS from the shared solution to the VM, VS removed my connection string info. Once I re added it everything started working.